Is it correct to recite this part of surah like this (described in detail in question body)?
Assalam-o-alaikum warahmatuAllahi wabarakatohu!
Following image shows a part of surah Yaseen.

My question is that will the highlighted part be read as aleemonillazi, or can it also be read as aleem. Allazi ...?

This question is similar to: What does the laa (لا) tajweed symbol mean when reciting the Qur'an?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Kind off funny both of these got asked in a relatively close time frame.

Pronouncing it as aleemonillazi or aleem. Allazi depends on if you waqf (stop) or not at the end of the verse.
It would be preferred if you pronunciate it as aleemonillazi according to the standard ruling of waqf in quran.

مـ compulsory stop to avoid altering the meaning. It’s an indicator for the required stop.
ط normal stop at the end of a sentence or thought
ج permissible stop. It’s an indicator for the sufficient stop.
صلي (or ز) permissible stop but preferable to continue. It’s an indicator for the good stop.
قلي permissible to continue but preferable to stop. It could be an indicator for a complete or sufficient stop.
لا  either not to cut off the recitation, or not to stop on the marked word and start on the following word. It’s an indicator of the repulsive stop.
قف The Anticipation Mark: preferable to stop.
∴ – The Embracing Stop: “Mu’aanaqah” is a sign found twice on two words from the Ayah, meaning if you want to stop on one of them, then you are not allowed to stop on the other. However, it’s permissible to continue without stopping on any of them as well.

THE لا above the verse stop suggests that you do not stop at the end of verse and continue reading as
aleemonillazi ja’ala lakum …
CONTINUITY is preferred because it preserves clarity of meaning of words.

I recite it as "aleemonillazi", but is it incorrect to say "aleem. allazi"? because I heard a qari recite like this. Should they be notified, or should they be left alone?

Also, jazakAllah for your answer and the summary of descriptions of different types of stops you provided. I didn't know any of that.

@Shy as long as the words are pronounced correctly and the meaning is not altered it is fine. I recommend you learn tajweed and see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-tajweed-is-it-necessary-to-learn-or-is-it-just-recommended

JazakAllah. Actually before today, I never thought of learning tajweed as a priority for now, because I wanted to go though the entire Quran's tafseer in detail (like Nouman Ali Khan explains) and then (if I am alive by then) hadith and then tajweed because I thought tajweed is an addendum but understanding Quran is a precursor to live according to Quran. But if I do want to start tajweed on the side, do you have any apps or book recommendations for someone who is working full time and has university in the evening. (I study tafseer in lunch/tea break or weekend)

@Shy It is important to know that tajwid is not necessary, it is just a way to beautify your recitation however if you are still interested, i recommend you see this youtube playlist https://youtu.be/oC_LBcbNCPM?si=odrmmkHOLxBGlmB_ and see this article https://www.getquranic.com/a-quick-guide-to-tajweed/, Also if you want a trusted scholar’s opinion of this i recommend you watch this video : https://youtu.be/LG2gi88570U?si=PoBrSGVOfZxO5jHm

JazakAllah a ton for the resources. May Allah bless you immensely. Ameen I'll inshaAllah look into these. JazakAllah again
